# Insert a draft blog post using Blogger API v3 with Python

Tags: python, blogger

I am trying to post an article using Blogger Api v3 client library.

https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/libraries

I was able to run this sample application to get my blog name and posts.

https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/tree/master/samples/blogger

I wrote this code to insert a post as draft, and I was able to create a draft. However, there is no body in it.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys

from oauth2client import client
from googleapiclient import sample_tools

def main(argv):
    # Authenticate and construct service.
    service, flags = sample_tools.init(
        argv, 'blogger', 'v3', __doc__, __file__,
        scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger')

    try:
        users = service.users()

        # Retrieve this user's profile information
        thisuser = users.get(userId='self').execute()

        blogs = service.blogs()

        # Retrieve the list of Blogs this user has write privileges on
        thisusersblogs = blogs.listByUser(userId='self').execute()

        posts = service.posts()

        blog = thisusersblogs['items'][0]
        if blog['id'] == '*** my_blog_id ***':
            posts.insert(blogId=blog['id'], body='test post', isDraft=True).execute()

    except client.AccessTokenRefreshError:
        print ('The credentials have been revoked or expired, please re-run'
               'the application to re-authorize')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

**Expected Result:** 'test post' in the drat post

**Actual Result:** No body in the draft post

Comment: just wanted to ask from where do i get the 'client_id' and 'client_secret' . ??

Comment: You should be able to find your credential in Google API Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to pass object in body instead of string just define an object like this

```
 body = {
        "kind": "blogger#post",
        "id": "6814573853229626501",
        "title": "posted via python",
        "content":"<div>hello world test</div>"
        }
 posts.insert(blogId=blog['id'], body=body, isDraft=True).execute()
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to solve my problem. I have one more question. Is "id" required in body? I was able to insert a post without id.

Comment: Post not working with patch when it is in DRAFT status.  But patches when it is live. How to resolve this  ?