# How to add imges in blogger api post insert with python

Tags: python, api, post, blogger

```
    posts = service.posts()
    body = {
        "kind": "blogger#post",
        "id": "" + str(post_id) + "",
        "title": "" + title + "",
        "content": "" + content + ""


        , "labels": [
            "software"
        ]

   }
    posts.insert(blogId=BlogId, body=body, isDraft=False, fetchBody=True, fetchImages=True).execute()
```

Comment: It is not exactly what You want but take look at [Insert a draft blog post using Blogger API v3 with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48527480/insert-a-draft-blog-post-using-blogger-api-v3-with-python)